# How to identify long running processes the Linux server

Tags: linux

I need to write a shell script to identify all the processes  which are running on the server for more than one day.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: This could help you https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7870/how-to-check-how-long-a-process-has-been-running

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17089/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-long-running-processes-that-match-a-particular-pattern